# Meaning of "humours (Elizabethan usage)"

Tags: meaning

I'm reading an article about Philip K. Dick written by Roger Zelazny. Zelazny talks about Dick's *Galactic Pot-Healer* and says:

> Galactic Pot-Healer -- When the encyclopedia defines a particular creature as the dominant life-form on a certain planet and then points out that the species only consists of one member ... This one is almost whimsical. But not quite. A Philip Dick book can never be categorized that neatly. But this one is a bit special in the focussing of its **humours (Elizabethan usage)** and in the almost pastoral quality of certain sections.

I'm confused about what Zelazny means by "humours (Elizabethan usage)". According to what I found on the internet, the word "humour" in Elizabethan time could mean "the characteristics that make up a man's temperament". Is that what Zelazny means?

I mean, he talks about how Dick cannot be categorized. Then he says Dick is special in focusing on his characters' temperaments and writing pastorally. I don't see the logic or relation between one thing and another. Can anybody explain the idea for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zelazny does not say that Dick's work cannot be categorized at all: he says that it cannot be categorized “that neatly”, referring to the immediately preceding categorization of *Galactic Pot-Healer* as “whimsical”.

He then substantiates this assertion by providing two further categories which may be brought to bear on *Galactic Pot-Healer*: [comedy of humours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comedy_of_humours) and [pastoral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pastoral), both of which were important genres in Elizabethan literature.